# Booting into Windows 10 kills my Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, uefi, windows-10

first: There are some other questions with nearly the same title, but with a different situation. So I don't think this is a duplicate.

I'm trying this on an old Alienware Area 51 R2 from 2014 with an UEFI BIOS. I've installed Windows 10 just like normal, then Ubuntu 16.04. My first problem began there: Grub doesnt showed up. I fixed this with Boot-Repair I've launched from my Ubuntu Live USB Stick. After executing `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi` Grub was finally showing on startup.

Now the problem is: When I run boot-repair I can boot into Ubuntu thousand times in a row. But when I boot into Windows once, I can't boot into Ubuntu anymore. Grub gets shown just like everytime, but when I select "Ubuntu" I get the Ubuntu loading screen but in a very low resolution, a blinking underscore in the top left corner. After a few seconds (about 5 to 10) it disappears, a single red dot from the 5 progress-dots remains for another 1 to 2 seconds and then my monitor gets no signal anmyore and turns off. Even after 30 minutes there is no response.

But booting in Windows works fine. When I run boot-repair again I can boot into Ubuntu with no problem until I boot into Windows for one time.

I can't imagine what informations you need. I would appreciate if you let me know.

Comment: Just a guess, but you may be running into problems with the *Windows* (not firmware) Fast Startup and/or Hibernate features. See [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) and [here,](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) respectively, for information on how to disable these two features.

Comment: Hey @RodSmith. Thanks, but Windows' Fast Startup is disabled already. The hibernate option doesn't even exists on my installation.